# what is the value of k after the following loop code has been executed?

Tags: loops

What is the value of k after the following loop code has been executed ?
Here is the pseudocode,

```
k := 0
for I1: = 1 to n
    for I2: = 1 to I1
        for Im := 1 to Im-1
            k:= k+1
```

The answer is : c(n+r-1,r)
I just can't figure out why the outcome is the r-combinations formula.c(n+r-1,r)
Need help please, thank you.

The question is from the book"discrete mathematics and its applications "
Ch 6.5 ex 6

Comment: If your third (innermost) loop correct? It seems it isn't. Also what is `r`?

Comment: Where does the variable `r` coming from?

Comment: Why not run it yourself and find out?

Answer (score 1):

The inner most loop will never run because Im can never be equal to Im-1..If this code is correct then the value of k will be equal to zero ! (Not changed)